# Access resources of different assembly

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-assembly

My program has the following structure where the boxes represent assemblies and the arrows represent references:

[image: Assembly structure]

The `WpfElements` assembly contains a resource dictionary in its Resources.xaml, which contains some styles:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="DialogDockStyle">
    ...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The `WpfControls` assembly contains a window, which references these styles:

```
<StackPanel ... Resources="{StaticResource DialogDockStyle}">
```

The `Server` and `Client` assemblies are executables that instantiate this window and display it.

This works great for the `Server`. The window is displayed and can be used. However, when the same code is run from the `Client`, an error occures instantiating the window:

> The resource with the name "DialogDockStyle" cannot be found.

It is a bit weird that is works from one assembly and not from the other. Is there anything I might have overseen to make it work from both assemblies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed to specify the resources in the `App.xaml` like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfElements;component/Resources.xaml"/>
            ...
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```